# How to handle certificate, while url is loading

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am getting the certificate popup when my URL is loading. It means `driver.get`  method is executing and code never moves to next line because `.get` method wait for url to fully loaded, but URL never loaded because certificate came in between. So there is any way to handle certificate while URL is loading?

I want to click ok on certificate

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser.

https://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html

For Firefox:
use profile and

```
ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) ;

ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
```

For Chrome:
    DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome () ;

```
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);
```